# How do i order the items in Codenameone hamburger menu

Tags: codenameone

How do I  order the items in Codenameone hamburger menu? I create the menus in the GUI builder in my preferred order but when it is displayed it appears in alphabetical order of the names of the menu items.[image: This is not the order that I have in the designer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items aren't ordered alphabetically, they should match the order in the designer although they might be exactly reversed.

[image]

Comment: They are ordered alphabetically. Pls check.

Comment: They are not, see attached picture. They are in the exact reverse order of add command.

Comment: you are right. exact reverse of the order in the designer.